# How to Autoclose my alert

Tags: javascript, php

Is there some way i can "Autoclose" this alert?

**CODE**

```
//Echo succes
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
  echo "alert('Välkommen ".$row['usr_fname']." ".$row['usr_lname']."');";
  echo 'window.location = "page.php"';
echo "</script>";
```

Comment: No, it's not possible to close `window.alert` programmatically. Only user himself can do it.

Comment: You can use a package like Bootstrap to create alerts that you can close. See: http://getbootstrap.com (many alternatives to this package exist)

Comment: For more details read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using one of many available scripts to do so, or write a function like this yourself. For starters, have a look at the jQuery UI modal component: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

The code could look something like this:

```
var $myDialog = $( '#dialog' );

$myDialog.dialog( {

    modal: true,
    open: function(){           
        setTimeout( function() { $myDialog.dialog( 'close' ); }, 3000 );    
    }

} );
```